# What is a Gmail Search that will Return All Emails with Tracking Numbers in Them?

Tags: gmail

Can someone show me a gmail search that will show me all of the emails that have either a United Parcel Service, United States Post Office, or a Federal Express tracking number in them?

Answer (score 2):

Try something along the lines of:

> +tracking +(fedex.com|usps.com|ups.com)

That will search all mail and only bring up when it matches the following:

- Includes the word "tracking"
- also includes either one of "fedex.com" or "usps.com" or "ups.com"

So if you have an email that mentions "tracking," but does not also mention or is from one of the mentioned in the parentheses, they will be skipped.

This should leave emails hand-waving you about the RFID implant in your shoulder from coming up in searches for tracking product and gift shipments from the various companies listed/searched.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to just search for the word "tracking". I dont think there is going to be one search that will get everything you want perfectly.